# Unable to connect to AWS Athena Workgroup using JDBC connection?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, jdbc, amazon-athena

I am using **JDBC to connect to Athena for a specific Workgroup**. But it is by default redirecting to the **primary workgroup**
Below is the code snippet

```
Properties info = new Properties();
        info.put("user", "access-key");
        info.put("password", "secrect-access-key");
        info.put("WorkGroup","test");
        info.put("schema", "testschema");
        info.put("s3_staging_dir", "s3://bucket/athena/temp");
info.put("aws_credentials_provider_class","com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain");
        Class.forName("com.simba.athena.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:awsathena://athena.<region>.amazonaws.com:443/", info);
```

As you can see I am using "Workgroup" as the key for the properties. I also tried "workgroup", "work-group", "WorkGroup". It is not able to redirect to the specified Workgroup. Always going to the default one i.e primary workgroup.

Kindly help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [release notes](https://s3.amazonaws.com/athena-downloads/drivers/JDBC/SimbaAthenaJDBC_2.0.13/docs/release-notes.txt) of Athena JDBC, the workgroup support is from v2.0.7.

If you jar is below this version, it will not work. Try to upgrade the library to 2.0.7 or above

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the issue was with the jar. Got it resolved long back. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to Override Client-Side Settings in workgroup.Enable below setting and rerun the query via JDBC. [image]

Check this [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/workgroups-settings-override.html) for more information.